# Figure numbering like 1-1 in the 1st chapter and 2-1 in the 2nd chapter

Tags: adobe-indesign, numbering

I need to create a document with numbered headings and numbered tables.

The tables in the 1st chapter should be numbered as 1-1, 1-2, etc. The tables in the 2nd chapter should be numbered as 2-1, 2-2, etc. And so on.

To create numbered headings, I have created a "Heading 1" paragraph style and adjusted its numbering as follows:

[image]

Then, following an article<sup>†</sup> by David Blatner, I have created another paragraph style and adjusted its numbering **as follows**:

[image]

However, it doesn't really work as I want it.

See the screenshot below. The last three tables should be numbered as 2-1, 2-2, and 2-3; not 1-4, 1-5, and 1-6.

[image]

What I'm doing wrong? How to make them to be numbered correctly?

<sup>†</sup> https://creativepro.com/figure-numbering-in-indesign-and-cross-references-to-them/

Comment: Wild guess: try and open the numbering settings for the 1-4 one, and set the mode to restart, as opposed to 'continue from previous'?

Comment: No, this works differently.

Comment: Ok, pity. Was worth a try :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, it seems I found a solution.

It was originally [posted](https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/creating-a-paragraph-style-for-numbering-figures-what-does-quot-h-quot-the-chapter-symbol-actually/m-p/9924905#M104346) by Barb Binder on Adobe forums.

Given that there are two levels of headings, the paragraph style used for table captions should be adjusted as follows:

[image]

And here is how my heading styles are adjusted, just in case.

Level-1 heading:

[image]

Level-2 heading:

[image]

Result:

[image]

**update**

If you have both figures and tables, they will use the same sequence! That is, if you have a table and then a figure, your table will be numbered as 1-1 and figure as 1-2. This is wrong, of course.

To workaround this, just increment values in *Level* and *Number* fields:

[image]

Comment: That’s clever! I never thought of using the Restart Numbers option for a level _not_ immediately above the current level.

Comment: Wow, very nice! You *will* get an upvote. I learned something from this. 

Comment: This does what I want except that "Restart numbers" is grayed out so that I can't select Level 1.  What have I done wrong?  (And thanks!)